# how to delete data permanently

Tags: permanent-delete

there is the whole recovery applications and commands .
I actually need to delete some sensitive data permanently so nobody can access it anymore , no matter what application they use or commands they carry on , any help ??

Comment: This isn't really ubuntu specific, but what you'll need to do is a multi-pass format which overwrites the drive with random data.

Comment: Here's a pretty robust guide: http://lifehacker.com/5153684/properly-erase-your-physical-media

Comment: Remove your hard drive, put some thermite on it and set it on fire to melt the hard drive platters for good. ;-] Wear some protective gear (hands, eyes/face, chest) like the guy at the bottom of [this blog post](https://frank.geekheim.de/?p=2423).

Answer (score 1):

There is no completely safe method except to destroy the hard disk drive completely (physically). But for most cases it should be enough to use [DBAN](https://dban.org/) to overwrite the drive.

You have to make a fresh installation after that, and you may want to use 'encrypted disk' alias LVM with encryption. An encrypted system is difficult to recover, so please **back it up** at regular intervals, and use a good passphrase, that you can remember, but other people cannot guess.

Answer (score 1):

See the `shred` command (and its `man` page for more info). For example, this truncates, overwrites, and then removes a file called writing.txt:

```
shred -uvz writing.txt
```

Update: Thanks to Andrius for the comment about modern filesystems. According to the GNU page on `shred`, the utility makes some assumptions about how filesystems work, and modern filesystems that use journaling could be problematic for `shred`. The GNU page notes, as a workaround, that it is probably more secure to use `shred` to shred a device, but even this is not a guarantee. Read more here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shred-invocation.html

The EFF has a how-to page, with some additional information, on using BleachBit to securely delete data on Linux:

https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/how-delete-your-data-securely-linux

Comment: shred doesn't work with modern filesystems. They simply write data to another place on disk (copy on write). So you will be just writing zeroes somewhere else without overwriting file.